# Trace and eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In the proof of Proposition 24 of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.1290v2.pdf), the following statement is made:

"The inequality $Tr(\xi)^2 \geq 1 − \gamma$ implies that the maximum eigenvalue of the Hermitian matrix $\xi$ is at least $1 − \gamma$"

The only property I have found is that $Tr(\xi) = \sum_j \lambda_j$ where $\lambda_j$ are the eigenvalues of $\xi$, thus we have that
$\sum_{i, j} \lambda_j\lambda_j \geq 1 − \gamma$, but I couldn't compare the maximum eigenvalue of $\xi$ with $1 - \gamma$.

Things that might help are that $\xi$ is an Hermitian linear operator in a 4-dimensional space and their eigenvalues are all non-negative and their values are at most $1$.

Comment: The authors might be wrong, or $\xi$ could have other properties. As this is a very recent paper, the authors should still remember the details and you may consider asking them directly.